# iOS Get errors in linking libraries that are designed for real devices not simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm running my project on simulator(using profile, cause I'm going to check if there exists leaks). Then I got the following warnings and errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Caesar/Documents/developer/objective-c/BoBanTang/BoBanTang/ShareSDK/Support/PlatformSDK/QQSDK/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Caesar/Documents/developer/objective-c/BoBanTang/BoBanTang/ShareSDK/Support/PlatformSDK/QQSDK/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiInterface", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BBTAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TencentOAuth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BBTAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But if I simply run it, without using profile, it can build successfully. I've searched for stackOverFlow and I've known that it was because this library is designed for real devices. But why I get different results using the 2 approaches to run my project? And I have used this library for some time, I haven't got this problem before(also using profile). Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building the TencentOpenAPI.framework yourself and using a workspace, this is a known issue discussed elsewhere on SO and in the dev forums.  The issue is that the individual projects don't know what platform the framework is when produced by another project.  They just see the file on disk and try to use it.  When you built for profiling, the framework was rebuilt for the newly selected platform.

Cleaning and rebuilding would likely also give you the same results.

Comment: So how can I solve it? Or I can only run it on a real device?

Comment: That depends on whether that is your framework or a 3rd party framework.  If it's yours, just build it for the simulator.  If it's from a 3rd party, ask them for a version that works with the simulator, or test on device.

Comment: It turns out that the 3rd party has just updated this framework so it no longer supports simulators under 5... I get it, much thx.